# How many binary strings of length n >= 4 are there that contain exact two instances of 10

Tags: combinatorics

Aa said in the title, The order of 10 matters , for example for n = 4 there is only one string which is 1010, or for n=5 there are 6 strings as following :
10101, 10100, 10110, 10010, 11010, 01010 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Compress the string into sections of $1$'s and $0$'s, so the string would be $0_a1_b0_c\dots$ or $1_a0_b1_c\dots$, where $a_b$ is $a$ repeated $b$ times. What are the possible compressed forms?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got confused even more than before, :( i'm sorry i'm still learning these stuffs.

Comment: @Element118  sorry, I got an answer but how to reach to that ? No explanation 
P(n+1,5)

Comment: please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49252/the-number-of-bit-strings-with-only-two-occurrences-of-01  answer seems to be ${n+1} \choose 5$

Comment: @abel thanks for the reply, but the problem is that I can't figure out how that solution works, he just says any such sequence can be written like this..! 1k0l1m0p1q0r.  But why ? Where do the 6 variables come from all of a sudden ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine the $n$ bits as asterisks in a line, mark the transitions $0\to 1$ as $+$ and the transitions $1\to 0$ as $-$. Then, we want to place two $-$ marks in the $n-1$ available positions, including a $+$ mark somewhere between them, and optionally a $+$ somewhere before and-or after them.

So we have the following count:

$${n-1 \choose 3}+{n-1 \choose 4}+{n-1 \choose 4}+{n-1 \choose 5}= \tag{1}$$
$$={n \choose 4}+ {n \choose 5} \tag{2}$$
$$={n+1 \choose 5} \tag{3}$$

In $(1)$, the combinatorial numbers correspond to the respective allowed patterns: 
$ ( - + - )$
$ (- + - +)$
$ ( + - + -)$
$ ( + - + - +)$.

Eqs $(2)$ and $(3)$ correspond to the [Pascal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) identity.

---

Update: an equivalent slightly simpler formulation would be: place an extra $0$ before the $n$ bits, and an extra $1$ after them. Then, considering the whole $n+1$ transitions available in the expanded $n+2$ string, we now have a single allowed pattern $(+ - + - +)$. Hence, the total count is

$${n+1 \choose 5} $$

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's so great , now I do have different approaches to this problem ..

Comment: @leonbloy: Nice approach! +1

Comment: nice approach +1. can you say how you arrived at/what motivated  this trick?

Comment: @abel Well, it's a pretty common approach, see "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" and examples http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294112/how-many-possible-words-of-this-type-can-be-formed

Comment: @leonbloy thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* We can model the situation with *generating functions*. But first let's analyse the problem.

> We consider binary strings consisting of $0s$ and $1s$ which contain precisely two substrings $10$.  We are looking for the number of strings with length $n\geq 4$. Each string has the shape
>   \begin{align*}
>   x10y10z
>   \end{align*}
>   with $x,y,z$ substrings of length $\geq 0$ which do *not* contain $10$.
>
> How could we describe *all* binary strings which do not contain $10$? They are precisely the strings which start with zero or more $0s$ followed by zero or more $1s$.

Let $$1^\star=\{\varepsilon,1,11,111,\ldots\}$$ denote all strings containing only $1$s with length $\geq0$. The empty string is denoted with $\varepsilon$. The corresponding generating function is $$w^0+w^1+w^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-w},$$ with the exponent of $w^n$ marking the length $n$ of a string of $1s$ and the coefficient of $w^n$ marking the number of strings of length $n$. Similarly we define $0^\star=\{\varepsilon,0,00,000,\ldots\}$.

> So, each of $x,y,z$ in the string $x10y10z$ is of the form $$0^\star1^\star$$ Since *concatenation* of strings correspond to *multiplication* of the corresponding generating functions we obtain for $x,y,z$
>   \begin{align*}
>   \left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^2
>   \end{align*}
>   All binary strings containing precisely two substrings $10$ can be described as
>   \begin{align*}
>   (0^\star1^\star)10(0^\star1^\star)10(0^\star1^\star)
>   \end{align*}
>
> Consequently we derive as generating function
>   \begin{align*}
>   w^4\left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^6
>   \end{align*}

$$ $$

> Since the number of binary strings of length $n \geq 4$ is encoded as coefficient of $[w^n]$ we finally obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   [w^n]&w^4\left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^6\\
> &=[w^{n-4}]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-6}{k}(-w)^k\\
> &=\binom{-6}{n-4}(-1)^{n}\\
> &=\binom{n+1}{5}\qquad\qquad n\geq 4
>   \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer and your time, I can understand through your solution but what about any shorter approach ? God bless you!

Comment: Can't we just say that there are 3 different space for x10x10x, which might be 1's and 0's then we have 3 0's, 3 1's , we end up having 6 ways, and move on like that ? Maybe i'm too wrong. :(

Comment: @bhd: Try to write down the $\binom{5}{5}=1$ string of length $4$, the $\binom{6}{5}=6$ strings of length $5$ and the $\binom{7}{5}=21$ strings of length $6$. Then you should see the pattern $0^\star1^\star$ somewhat more clearly in action.

Comment: i'm really grateful for you help master! You did me a great favor! Thanks a billion , now I can fully understand it!